# Python not configured for Tk

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and Python 3.3.4 using **pyenv**. I have no problem using other modules. When I enter python console and write

```
import tkinter
```

It outputs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/serdar/.pyenv/versions/3.3.4/lib/python3.3/tkinter/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I already installed `python3-tk` and `tk-devel`.

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/python3 -c'import tkinter'` succeed?

Comment: Yes it worked but **pyenv** installs multiple version. You can change active python version with single command. It installs under ~/.pyenv/versions. `~/.pyenv/versions/3.3.4/bin/python3 -c'import tkinter'` didn't worked.

Comment: if it works with `/usr/bin/python3` then try to recreate the environment

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian JFI: [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) works different from regular virtualenvs.

Comment: if you are using `pyenv` for Python environments management and want IDLE work there is step by step guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61870688/idle-and-tkinter-issue-with-tk-using-pyenv

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to have the Tk development files/headers available during `pyenv install`.

On Ubuntu (15.04) the following should provide them: `sudo apt-get install tk-dev`.

After this, `pyenv install 3.4.3` (or `pyenv install 2.7.10` etc) should pick it up and have support for Tk.

([Reference issue in pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/issues/94#issuecomment-31371552))

Comment: this should probably go in the pyenv faq

Comment: I just added it to the requirements in common-build-problems wiki page

Comment: For Red Hat / Amazon Linux, this is: `sudo yum install tkinter`

Comment: I'm having the same issue on MacOS. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: This was my issue. I was still trying to get it to work without creating a new env

Answer (score 18):

This is a guide for Mac users,

1. Uninstall your python version. For example: `pyenv uninstall 3.7.2`
2. Install TK: `brew install tcl-tk`
3. Follow the post install steps and config tk:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include"
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin
```

4. Reload your terminal session and make sure all settings above are correctly set
5. Install python: `pyenv install 3.7.2`

The **TK** should work now

Comment: thats correct. I've just posted the step by step guide for ones who may need it -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61870688/idle-and-tkinter-issue-with-tk-using-pyenv

Comment: **ACTUALLY** What solved my problem is: `brew install python-tk` and not the tcl... thing.

Comment: thanks @JohnnyJS, your solution works for me. btw i'm on python-3.9

Comment: @JohnnyJS same here, your tip did it.  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

For Mac users,

1. Uninstall pyenv completely: `brew uninstall pyenv && rm -rf ~/.pyenv`.
2. install zlib, tcl-tk and pyenv

```
brew update
brew install zlib
brew install tcl-tk #otherwise we may have problems with tf package
brew install pyenv
```

3. Make compilers find zlib. Add this to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc (if you youse oh-my-zsh)

```
# For compilers to find zlib you may need to set:
export LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="${CPPFLAGS} -I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"

# For pkg-config to find zlib you may need to set:
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH} /usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Then you are set up!. For more details check [this](https://gist.github.com/SebastiaAgramunt/5185ccf8637e69f611bd1217a98289b2) github gist.

Comment: If you just want to run a tool that requires tk, you can use `pipx` to create a venv and script that goes into $PATH to launch it without interfering with PyEnv etc. E.g. to run the Thonny GUI using Homebrew's Python + TK libraries: `brew install python python-tk && cd /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6_1/bin && ./python3 -m pip install pipx && ./python3 -m pipx install thonny && cd && .local/bin/thonny`