# No IDLE for Python 3 but .python exe is working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python 2.7 it is perfectly working but 3.x vision is not opening after successful installation i using the right os and bit as comparable in my PC. But python.exe is working. in cmd.exe it shows report:

> Your python may not be configure for Tk. **

can you help me please.

Comment: what error is it giving to you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550068/python-not-configured-for-tk